# Not able to load KSQL table in Arcadia BI Tool

Tags: confluent-platform, ksqldb

I am trying to create a streaming visualization from KSQLDB using Arcadia BI tool. I am able to establish a connection and see the streams and tables in KSQLDB from Arcadia. But while trying to sample data, I am getting error.Can anyone help?

```
Error running query: Error: b'{"@type":"statement_error","error_code":40001,"message":"Pull queries don\'t support LIMIT clauses. Refer to https://cnfl.io/queries for info on query types. If you intended to issue a push query, resubmit with the EMIT CHANGES clause\\n\\nQuery syntax in KSQL has changed. There are now two broad categories of queries:\\n- Pull queries: query the current state of the system, return a result, and terminate. \\n- Push queries: query the state of the system in motion and continue to output results until they meet a LIMIT condition or are terminated by the user.\\n\\n\'EMIT CHANGES\' is used to to indicate a query is a push query. To convert a pull query into a push query, which was the default behavior in older versions of KSQL, add `EMIT CHANGES` to the end of the statement before any LIMIT clause.\\n\\nFor example, the following are pull queries:\\n\\t\'SELECT * FROM X WHERE ROWKEY=Y;\' (non-windowed table)\\n\\t\'SELECT * FROM X WHERE ROWKEY=Y AND WINDOWSTART>=Z;\' (windowed table)\\n\\nThe following is a push query:\\n\\t\'SELECT * FROM X EMIT CHANGES;\'\\n\\nNote: Persistent queries, e.g. `CREATE TABLE AS ...`, have an implicit `EMIT CHANGES`, but we recommend adding `EMIT CHANGES` to these statements.","stackTrace":[],"statementText":"select * from table_name limit 10;","entities":[]}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with Arcadia and the version of KSQL that you're running.

There was a [breaking change in ksqlDB 0.6](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/releases/tag/v0.6.0-ksqldb) (shipped with Confluent Platform 5.4) which changed the syntax of queries. Pull queries were added and the previous "continuous queries" are known as "push queries" and denoted with a mandatory `EMIT CHANGES` clause.

Comment: I am using confluentinc/cp-ksql-server:5.4.1 which is available in docker

Comment: Right. So you are using the newer version, which requires a different syntax from that which Arcardia is generating when it calls KSQL.

Comment: I checked with Arcadia team, they told that it currently works with only 5.1 version of KSQL

Comment: If my answer is correct, or helpful, please do mark it as such :)